# Case returns more than one value when using it with join

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, case, amazon-redshift

I have a problem using case and join together in redshift
(This is not my real data, its just for the example so max doesnt help me).
here is my query:

```
select a.num1, 
(case when b.param = 'd' then b.param
when b.param = 'c' then b.param
when b.param = 'b' then b.param
when b.param = 'a' then b.param end)
from table a inner join table b on a.num1 = b.num1
```

for table a:

[image]

and for table b:

[image]

the result I get are:

[image]

but I only want to get the first match for the case for each 'num1', like:

[image]

How can I achieve that? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was solved at 
[another question I've opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51356873/case-returns-more-than-one-value-with-join).

I needed to use [coalesce](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_NVL_function.html):

```
SELECT a.id,
       COALESCE( MAX(CASE WHEN b.param_type = 'Ignition' THEN a.param_value END), 
                 MAX(CASE WHEN b.param_type = 'Turn' THEN a.param_value END),
                 MAX(CASE WHEN b.param_type = 'Speed' THEN a.param_value END),
                 MAX(CASE WHEN b.param_type = 'Break' THEN a.param_value END)
               ) as value
FROM public.tbl_a a JOIN
     public.tbl_b
     ON b.id = a.id
GROUP BY a.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

For this data, you can use `max()`:

```
select a.num1, 
       max(case when b.param = 'd' then b.param
                when b.param = 'c' then b.param
                when b.param = 'b' then b.param
                when b.param = 'a' then b.param
           end)
from table a inner join
     table b
     on a.num1 = b.num1
group by a.num1;
```

This can be simplified to:

```
select a.num1, max(b.param)
from table a inner join
     table b
     on a.num1 = b.num1
group by a.num1;
```

This answers the question that you asked.  This probably doesn't solve your actual problem.  I would suggest that you ask *another* question, with more appropriate sample data and a a better description of what you want to do.